# Redirect to https using ngrok

Tags: ngrok

Hi i am using ngrok to serve my web application hosted in Apache tomcat running on my machine. I am following commamd to run ngrok

```
ngrok tls -region=us -hostname secure.example.com -key mydoamin.key -crt mydoamin.crt 80
```

Its works fine in HTTPS but when i access my domain using http it says Tunnel secure.example.com  not found. I think by using tls it is only exposing https what i want is to redirect user from HTTP to HTTPS. Can i achieve this using ngrok?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have found a solution to your problem.
Here my solution.
To use it, you must have your certs.

ngrok.yml

```
authtoken: <your token>
region: <your region>
tunnels:
   <name-https>:
   addr: 8443
   crt: path/to/cert/cert.pem
   key: path/to/key/key.pem
   host_header: "rewrite"
   proto: tls
   hostname: www.myexample.test
<name-https>:
   addr: 80
   proto: http
   bind-tls: false
   hostname: www.myexample.test
```

Navigate to the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and create a new file `nano example.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myexemple
    Redirect permanent / https://www.myexample.test
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8443>
     ServerName <servername>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<your-project>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Save all and start the commands:

```
a2ensite example.conf
systemctl reload apache2
```

Reach the location of your `ngrok.yml` file and start it with the command:

```
ngrok start --all
```